Not able to test payments using Authoriz.Net on my localhost environment
Earlier I was able to make payments on my webform application using Authorize.Net but since last few months I am not able to do payment in my localhost environment.
Have recieved no help from Auth.net documentations.
This the error that it gives normally "Invalid Setting Value. hostedPaymentIFrameCommunicatorUrlurl: must begin with https://."
Infact I am using https:// already
I tried hosting on IIS with SSL and many other things but didn't work

You can't. For "Security" the prohibit the use of localhost. You can either use 127.0.0.1 or setup a dummy domain locally. We wound up using the 127.0.0.1 as it was easier.
There are a number of posts on the Authorize.net Developer community forum about this (and the lack of any reference to this change in their documentation)

I tried setting up for 127.0.0.1 by publishing on IIS but it didn't work for me. Could you please specify how to make things work?
